# Scrapy crawl only the base domain links (or first level links)

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, web-scraping, scrapy

I am implementing a crawl spider that crawls the webpage and look for the same domain links and then crawls all that same domain pages. so far i successfully implement the crawl spider that extract all the links from the web-page, here is the rule that gets all

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'', )),
         callback='parse_start_url', follow=False),
```

and then i apply a check in the callback function, that is something like this

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    request_url = response.request.headers.get('referer', " ")
    if (request_url in response.url) or (request_url == " "):

        # retrieving the text from he body of the page
        mystring = ''.join(sel.xpath("//body//text()").extract()).strip()
```

the above if condition is working fine for me but the problem is that it goes to all the link available on a given page and decision is made in the **callback function** , i want the Rule (link-extractor) help so that it only crawl the page that has the same base domain.
or we can say that the link of that given site only.

any help will be highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: There's a middleware for this: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite

Comment: @Blender actually i am populating the url from this method;
def start_requests(self):  and in this method i fetch the records from database.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what method generates these requests. The spider middleware will ignore them.

Comment: okay .

@Blender can you describe a bit more the usage of middleware??
as i havn't used it yet.

Comment: Just give your spider a class attribute `allowed_domains` with the list of allowed domains and it'll work.

Comment: i created a allowed _url attribute and assign it a value like this
allowed_domains = []

and in the method    
        def start_requests(self):
i assign the value like this 
self.allowed_domains = rows

but the results still got this sort of messages


<GET http://www.facebook.com/pages/A-Return-to-Health/160435208670> (referer: http://areturntohealth.com)

whereas the facebook.com is not a allowed_url

Any hint from your side???